# external stylesheet not showing any style but internal one does

Tags: php, html, css

when ever i am putting all the style in the style tag it is working fine but if i put those codes in an external stylesheet it is not showing any style in frontend.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php $title; ?></title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
                        <th>post ID</th>
                        <th>post title</th>
                        <th>post Description</th>
                        <th>Author</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                      </tr>
        <?php 
            foreach($posts as $post)
            {

                echo "
                        <tr>
                        <td>".$post->Post_id."</td>
                        <td>".$post->post_title."</td>
                        <td>".$post->Post_description."</td>
                        <td>".$post->author."</td>
                        <td>".$post->date."</td>
                        </tr>
                "   ;     
            }
            ?>


    </table>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and my external stylesheet is
/* CSS Document */

```
table{
    width:1000px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
    }
th{
    background:#0CC;
    animation-direction:normal;
    height:50px;
    }
td{
    height:50px;
    background:#396;
    color:#FFF;
    }
```

i donot understand what is wrong.

Comment: Can you try this in php? `if(file_exists("css/style.css")) echo "Yes";` maybe it's wrong path? Just to be clear, I want this in between <body> and </body>

Comment: Why do you post a table between head and body? It's after </head> and before <body>. Are you sure that is correct?

Comment: @DSaha any luck with the answers?

Comment: yes it is my mistake to put the table tag in wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML `<table>` should be placed between the `<body></body>`.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm, why is the table tag in the head part? There you should place only meta data, script data and all like, as far as I know / meta tags, script tags, title tag, link to bootstrap for example /. You should place your table tag in the body part and everything should be fine. Remember, the part in the head is NOT visible on you web page, only the things you put in the body. Hope that fixes your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php $title; ?></title>
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
<tr>
                    <th>post ID</th>
                    <th>post title</th>
                    <th>post Description</th>
                    <th>Author</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                  </tr>
    <?php 
        foreach($posts as $post)
        {

            echo "
                    <tr>
                    <td>".$post->Post_id."</td>
                    <td>".$post->post_title."</td>
                    <td>".$post->Post_description."</td>
                    <td>".$post->author."</td>
                    <td>".$post->date."</td>
                    </tr>
            "   ;     
        }
        ?>


</table>

</body>
</html>
```